# Saving to UserDefaults from UITableViewCell causes crash Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, swift4.2

A UISwitch is placed within a UITableViewCell, when switch is toggled want to save the state of the switch to UserDefaults.

```
class SettingsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   @objc fileprivate func switchToggled(_ cellSwitch: UISwitch) {
        if let option = self.option {
            switch option.tag {
            case 1:
                let state = cellSwitch.isOn
                SettingsValues.standard.setState(state)
            default:
                print(">>> Settings Cell >> Tag for option does not exist")
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

On viewDidLoad it works fine and it saves to UserDefaults, however the moment you scroll the cell off screen, its dequeued. When you scroll back and flip the switch it cause a crash:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x20)
```

The SettingsValues is a custom singleton, the function saves to UserDefaults. I have tried moving the saving out of UITableViewCell through a protocol to the ViewController but it still causes a crash when saving to UserDefaults.

I feel it has something to do with the dequeue nature of the TableViewCell but I don't understand what is happening hence not sure how to tackle this problem.

EDIT: 
The singleton

```
final class SettingsValues: NSObject {
   static let standard = SettingsValues()

   private override init() { super.init() }

   @objc dynamic var state: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kEnableState) {
       didSet {
           saveSettingsState()
       }
   }

   private func saveSettingsState() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(state, forKey: kEnableState)
   }

   func setState(_ bool: Bool) {
        self.state = bool
   }
}
```

The crash is on line `UserDefaults.standard.set(state, forKey: kEnableState)`.
I set a breakpoint on that line and when I press step over, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` occurs

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint to figure out where exactly the crash occurs. Your code looks harmless.

Comment: I doubt that this code crashes. Set the exception breakpoint to get more information. Basically `UserDefaults` is inappropriate to save UI states in a table view. Add a property to the data model to keep the state.

Comment: where you set switchToggled action ?? post full context

Comment: I added the Singleton. The thing is when the viewController loads and you don't scroll the table such that the cell disappears, you can flip the switch as many times as you want. But the moment that cell scrolls off screen when you scroll back and flip the switch it crashes. But the save still happens, so when you open the app again that bool is saved. I used the custom singleton because i attached an observer.

Comment: Im saving the state for when the app is opened again.

Comment: Why is state declared dynamic, are you calling your Singleton from objective-c?

Comment: No there is an observer attached to that variable

Comment: Do you mean didSet? It doesn't need dynamic as far as I know.

Comment: Not the property observer. Its KVC/KVO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. It was because of the observers. There was another cell in the `tableView` that had an observer for the state. I did not remove the observer on `deinit`hence multiple instances of the observer was added everytime the cell got dequeued and redrawn.

Lesson to all watch how many times your observers are being created for the same reference object. I won't go so far to always remove on `deinit` sometimes `deinit` won't ever be called. Example: a viewcontroller on the tabbarcontroller.
Safer bet would be to watch the number of created instances. In this case I should have removed the observer on `deinit`

Thanks to all who left a comment and helped jiggle things up